# check head mercurial python hook is not working in version 4.6.1

Tags: python-2.7, mercurial, hook, mercurial-hook

I am working on Hg python hook.These hooks are currently running on Hg version 2.2.1 fine but now we are planning to upgrade Hg to Higher version 4.6.1 and I found the issue with below hook on higher version with error

```
def chkheads(ui, repo, **kwargs):
        ui.status(_('chkheads hook\n'))
        for b in repo.branchtags():
            if len(repo.branchheads(b)) > 1:
                ui.status(_("Two heads found n branch '%s'\n" % b))
                ui.status(_('Only one head is allowed\n'))
                return 1
```

> > Error:
> >     for b in repo.branchtags():
> >     AttributeError: 'lfilesrepo' object has no attribute 'branchtags'

Has this branchtags() method been removed from 4.6.1 hg version?If yes, is there any way to do the checkheads in hg 4.6.1 version?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can now the `branchmap` method on the repository instance. According to the source (https://www.mercurial-scm.org/repo/hg/file/4.6.1/mercurial/localrepo.py#l1038), it should returns a dictionary: `{branch: [branchheads]}`.

Comment: @othiraldan I used the branchmap and gives me the list of all branches.Please see above in answer

Answer (score 1):

The best way to access this kind of information is now the `branchmap` object.

```
def checkheads(ui, repo, **kwargs):
    """Only allow pushing a single head"""
    ui.status(_('checkheads hook\n'))
    branchdata = repo.branchmap()
    for b in branchdata.iterbranches():
        heads = branchdata.branchheads(b)
        if 1 < len(heads):
            ui.status(_("Two heads detected on branch '%s'\n") % b)
            ui.status(_('Only one head per branch is allowed\n'))
        return 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Now if I print b then it gives me the list of all branches and the value of test variable is 0 for all closed branches whereas 1 for all opened branches

```
def checkheads(ui, repo, **kwargs):
    """Only allow pushing a single head"""
    ui.status(_('checkheads hook\n'))
    for b in repo.branchmap():
        print b
        test = len(repo.branchheads(b))
        print test
        if len(repo.branchheads(b)) > 1:
            ui.status(_("Two heads detected on branch '%s'\n" % b))
            ui.status(_('Only one head per branch is allowed\n'))
            return 1
```